# Ambient occlusion, getting dark hard edges on texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

When I am baking the Cycles AO from a high poly model to a low poly, I am getting dark areas with sharp edges where they are not suppose to be (as shown in the image below). Anyone geting the same problem or am i doing something wrong?[image]

Update: I got it to work when i remodeled everything in a new scene, some setting that I can't fin must have messed up the old model. (it did not work when appending or copying the old model in a new scene.)

Comment: What happens if you scale up the low poly to completely cover the high poly?

Comment: @JtheNinja It did not work.

Comment: It's hard to make out the problem without looking at the file .Consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and post the link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You checked "cage" for baking but from what I see you have not chosen a cage object. Untick the cage object, then change the extrusion to a higher value.

Comment: Did not work, i had it checked when i was trying to make it work. But with the cage option off or on (with a cage) i was still getting the same result.